# What is the concise summary of Jared Kushner's foreign policy views?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

A current story *du jour* among politics watchers in US is the palace intrigue involving [Kushner vs Bannon](https://www.google.com/search?q=kushner%20and%20bannon) (even the typically more-birds-eye observers at FiveThirtyEight podcast have joined in the fun).

Bannon's foreign policy views are somewhat well articulated and publicized (although they are often misrepresented, it seems to me, if I compare what's been reported to what he actually said).

But is there a good source and/or concise summary of Jared Kushner's foreign policy views?